# How can I write comments in JavaScript and when?

Tags: javascript, comments

How to write comments in JavaScript and when?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way of code comments in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815903/what-is-the-correct-way-of-code-comments-in-javascript)

Comment: Please consult your preferred JavaScript tutorial or search provider for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of comment you want to write: single-line or multi-line.
For single-line, you can try this:

// I am a comment
For multi-line:
/* I am a
multi-line comment */

Check out this [tutorial](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-and-when-to-write-comments-in-javascript.html), for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiline command use this

```
/**
 * This is my multiline command
*/
```

And if you want inline command then simply use this

```
// This is my inline command
```

Answer (score 1):

To comment out single line, you may use `//`

Example

```
//This Button is for linking and demo
<Button>Click Me</Button>
```

Another way, you would use `/*` for start and  `*/` for closing

Example

```
/*Describe my whole js file what am I doing
This js include three function which was...
also that...
finally...
*/
```

try this [article](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/javascript-comment), you will get a better understanding for JavaScript comments